# format specifier inside format specifier to change size of leading zeros

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I was thinking to solve my issue that is described in the following and then I ended with a question that I couldn't find an answer for it on Google.

Question: Is it possible to use format specifier inside another format specifier in printf()?

The issue is with size of leading zeros in printf() in following line of code:

```
uint16_t num=5;
printf("%02d",num);
```

Is it possible to use a format specifier for that "2"?
How can I adjust the size of leading zeros in the program based on different conditions (so it would be like %02d,%03d,%04d,...)? Except defining different categories and different printf() lines, is it possible to use a trick here? Is there any other function, rather than printf(), to solve the issue?

Comment: It is possible for `printf` but, alas, not for `scanf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See `*` width specifier of `printf`. Example:

```
printf("%0*d\n", 5, 2);
```

... prints:

```
00002
```